# Hash Table or map implementation

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list, hash-map, hashcode

I'd like to get feedback on whether my hash table is correct or not. Also, any ideas on performance?

```
    template<class J,class K>
class List {
private:
    struct Node {
        J key;K data;

        Node * next;
        Node(J _key,K _data):key(_key),data(_data),next(nullptr) {}
    }*head;

public:
    List():head(nullptr){}
    ~List() {
        deleteNode();
    }
    void insert(J _key ,K _data) {
            Node * newNode = new Node(_key, _data);
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
    }

    void traverse() {
        for(Node * curr = head; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->next) {
            cout<< "( "<<curr->key << ", " << curr->data << " )" << " ";
        }
    }

    K search(J key) {
        if (!empty()){

            for(Node * curr = head;curr != nullptr;curr = curr->next) {
                if (curr->key == key) {
                    return curr->data;
                }
            }
        }

        return K(-1);
    }

    bool empty() { return (head == nullptr); }

    void deleteNode() {
        Node * tmp = nullptr;
        for(Node * curr = head; curr != nullptr;){
            tmp = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = tmp;
        }
    }
};

template<class KEY, class VALUE>
class myHash {
private:

    struct bucket {
        List<KEY,VALUE> list_at_bucket;
    }*Buckets;

    int tableSize;
public:
    myHash(int size) {
        tableSize = size;
        Buckets = new bucket[tableSize];
    }

    ~myHash() {
        for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            Buckets[i].list_at_bucket.deleteNode();
        }
    }



    void put(KEY k, VALUE value) {
        int getCode = hash(k);
         Buckets[getCode].list_at_bucket.insert(k,value);
    }


    VALUE getValue(KEY _key) {
        int getCode = hash(_key);
        return  Buckets[getCode].list_at_bucket.search(_key);
    }

    bool contains(KEY _key) {
        int getCode = hash(_key);
        if (Buckets[getCode].list_at_bucket.search(_key) != -1) {
            return  true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // need a template hash function
    int hash(KEY key) const {
        int value = 0;
        for (char each: key) {
            value += each;
        }
        return  value % tableSize;
    }

    void traverse() {
        for (int index = 0; index <tableSize; index++){
            cout<< "[" << index << " ]-> ";
            Buckets[index].list_at_bucket.traverse();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @jamal the code works

Comment: You're also asking some off-topic questions, particularly ones regarding adding new code.

Comment: are you talking about the comment in the code ?

Comment: Yes, and some below the code, such as making keys unique and implementing a generic hash function.

Comment: i removed all comments

Comment: I've restored the other on-topic question, about performance.

Comment: @mello: You do  know there is already a standard hash table in C++. It is called `std::unordered_map<K,V>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a lott to say:

1. `K` and `V` are the traditional template-arguments for keys and values in C++.
   Why do you use `J` and `K` respectively `KEY` and `VALUE` instead?
2. `List::Node` is only instantiated at one place, where all three members are set. Why then does it have a constructor at all, and one setting the last one to `nullptr` at that?
3. Default copy- and move- construction and assignment are completely unsuited to your `List`, as it owns its nodes. Leaving them leads to double-deletes and abandoned nodes. Look at the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

   Also worth a look are inclass-initializers (for `head`).
4. `deleteNode` looks more like `reset`, and should zero `head` or be inlined into the destructor. As-is, it leaves `head` dangling...
5. The same comments apply to copying / moving / assigning `myHash` as to `List`.
6. The `myHash` dtor leaks the array of buckets...
7. `contains` should return the condition directly, instead of putting it into an if-clause. `if(somebool) return true; else return false;` is a bit wordy.
8. Your `traverse`-functions would be more appropriately named `dump` or some such... Anyway, why don't you overload `operator>>(std::ostream, yourtypehere)` instead?
9. Your `hash`-function runs afool of the fact that only the type itself can know which parts are relevant and how to hash them. Take a look at the design of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).
10. Next, I would suggest embracing `auto`, see [Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: can i add the changes onto the original question ? so you could tell me if i have done them right